# Selecting features in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I loaded in a property / parcel map into QGIS, but I can't figure out how to select parcels by click on them.  In the table view, I can select parcels by selecting rows in the table, but I need to be able to visually select them (so that I can export them to a new layer).

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 
select a layer and open the layer attribute table for this layer

then  clicking by toolbar on botton rectangle with arrow and inner yellow square

[image]

for activate the click selecting geometries

then check the geometry you prefer

the selected  geometry became yellow